# Is there a way to get Rails to guess a resource's #edit path the same way it does with the #show path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, you can do `link_to "text", resource` or `url_for resource` and Rails will try to guess the path to the resource from the resource's class and id. Is there any way to do the same by for the edit link?

I could probably have something together to just append `"/edit"` the the `#show` path, but that doesn't seem very pleasant.

Side question: is there a way to get the collection path for a model given the model class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
link_to 'Edit This Thing', [:edit, @thing] # = edit_thing_path(@thing)
link_to 'Things Index', Thing # = things_path
```

These call `polymorphic_path` under the hood, as you already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I found `polymorphic_path`, which seems to do the trick. You call it in this fashion:

```
polymorphic_path([:edit, resource])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
link_to "text", edit_resource_path(resource)
```